# Android Emulator Skin - To be Set or No Set?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

When the skin for Nexus 10 android emulator it does not pick up the created layout-landscape but when I set No skin option it picks it up.

1. Should the emulator skin be set or not set?
2. Why does it not pick up the layout-landscape when the skin is set? (If the skin is just for appearance why does this happen)

Thanks for your response in advance!

Comment: ... is this a tragedy?! I never use skins - which are only intended for beauty purposes (and slow down your emulator loading).

Comment: Thanks! I am a beginner and just got confused bcos it was behaving differently with the skin. Wasted the whole of yesterday trying to figure out why I was not getting the layout I wanted until I removed the skin.